# Storing Documents and Graph in the same collection of DocumentDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

So I am experimenting with CosmosDb and looking to use the Gremlin API for Vertex and Edge queries. I have a number of entities which will have multiple edge connections between such as "knows","trusts","likes" etc

I do however wish to have complex documents as vertices, so rather than use the gremlin syntax of text query with many properties (this seems very cumbersome) I have inserted documents using the documentDB API. Problem is once a document has been added (which comes back with query correctly and shows in the SQL query) I cannot then make any g.V() calls without getting a an error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.
```

I also can't add edges to these vertices.

So my question is, am I trying to do this the wrong way? Should my complex objects be held in a separate collection and then mirror their ids onto vertexes in a new collection?

Can you not use the Gremlin API and the Document API on the same collection?

Thanks for any advice.

Richard

**Update for Oliver**

This is the simple test document which creates fine using the documentdb library and  is then shown when I perform an SQL Select * from c in the data explorer:

```
 {
        "id": "beea4756-2a25-4e2e-a7d9-457ad03dd56d",
        "title": "Test item",
        "description": "Test description",
        "purchaseUrl": "http://www.test.co.uk",
        "imageUrls": [
            "http://www.test.com",
            "http://www.test2.com"
        ],
        "label": "item",
        "created": "2017-10-09T12:41:49.0201322Z",
        "modified": "2017-10-09T12:41:49.0203021Z",
        "createdById": "TestUserId",
        "modifiedById": "TestUserId",
        "_rid": "jXNCAKbsIQABAAAAAAAAAA==",
        "_self": "dbs/jXNCAA==/colls/jXNCAKbsIQA=/docs/jXNCAKbsIQABAAAAAAAAAA==/",
        "_etag": "\"00000629-0000-0000-0000-59db6e8d0000\"",
        "_attachments": "attachments/",
        "_ts": 1507552909
    }
```

and this is the error I get when I use g.V() in the graph explorer in the Azure portal (or when I try any gremlin query or edge creation in my code):

```
    System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.
   at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Convert[T,U](T token)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.<Convert>d__14`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.VertexPropertyField.Replace(JProperty jproperty)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.VertexField..ctor(GraphCommand graphCommand, JObject vertexObject)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Common.VertexObjectCache.AddOrUpdateVertexField(VertexCompositeKey vertexKey, JObject vertexObject)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.DocumentDBRuntime.<GetVertices>d__1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.FetchNodeOperator.<ComputeNextRecordAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.GraphExecutionOperator.<NextAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.ProjectOperator.<ComputeNextRecordAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.GraphExecutionOperator.<NextAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.GraphTraversal.GraphTraversalIterator.<CurrentOperatorNextAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.GraphTraversal.GraphTraversalIterator.<MoveNextAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.GraphTraversal.<MoveNextAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.GremlinDocumentQuery`1.<ExecuteNextAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.GremlinDocumentQuery`1.<ExecuteNextAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Portal.PlatformProxy.Graph.Controllers.GremlinQueriesController.<SubmitQueryAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Portal.PlatformProxy.Graph.Controllers.GremlinQueriesController.<Post>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: I'm from Azure CosmosDB Graph team. We do support Gremlin API and Document API on the same collection, so this looks like a bug. 
Can you provide a sample document which repro's this issue in your question? Also are you using the latest Microsoft.Azure.Graphs package?

Comment: Thanks for the update Oliver, I will put my code in a sample for you to test. I am using latest betas: "Microsoft.Azure.Graphs" Version="0.3.0-preview" and "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core" Version="1.5.1" more soon

Comment: Hi Richard, can you send out an email to AskCosmosDBGraphAPI@microsoft.com and include the link to this question. The team can work with you directly to try and get this unblocked.

Comment: OK will do, thanks Oliver

Comment: @Richard - were you able to get this resolved? I'm getting the same exception when trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to mix and match the Graph and Document APIs in the same collection. However, it will only work if you insert the vertices and edges in the GraphSON format that is expected for graph documents. If you test running some gremlin inserts for both edges and vertices and then inspect the format of the documents in your collection by using the Document API you will see what the expected format looks like.

At my work we've built out a custom ORM that takes the C# POCOs representing our vertices and edges and builds up the appropriate structure using reflection before using the Document API to do the actual inserts. This way you get the best of both worlds.

The other option you've mentioned here of having one collection for representing pure relationship and another for storing the actual documents could also be a viable solution depending on the nature of the application you're building. There would definitely be a performance hit in the form of making extra network calls to fill in the actual documents as well as missing out on transactions in the form of SPROCs, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jesse, I have been looking at the graphson format but had read that only graphson format properties are returned on gremlin queries but that the document could be added as standard documentdb documents. Having seen the comment from Oliver above I am going to check out what they say first and then reassess. Again, thanks for the reply. Your method sounds like the way I will have to go if this is not a bug.

Comment: @Jesse Carter: I have been looking into defining relationships separately. Is there anything out there that I could read further into? Say I want to store the "pure entities" in an RDBMS or NoSQL DB. Then I could define the relatioinships as something like *(E,V), embed* or *relational* (it's not that simple actually, just making a point). This has to be a problem more people than just you and me thought of. Can you point me in a direction where I can dig further? I'm struggling to find info regarding this topic.

Comment: @MichaelSchnerring I've actually started working on a Node/Typescript library that simplifies using Cosmos for these kinds of scenarios. https://github.com/WonderPanda/NoSequel Right now there's a big focus on Cassandra (as it pertains to client work I'm doing right now) but I have plans to support both Gremlin and DocumentDB APIs. I'm curious to know what reasons you have for moving the pure entities into a separate DB service?

Comment: It's not about moving pure entities and relations to a separate DB service per se. It's more like moving the relations away from the pure entities, regardless of DB provider. My initial thought was being able to support any kind of entity and kind of "choose" the DB provider that fits your needs best - like your reflection ORM. Doing this isn't trivial though.
I have pondered and crawled the net yesterday and found [Prisma](https://github.com/graphcool/prisma), formerly known as graphcool. It has really taken off (1.0 released in Jan 18) and might actually be my silver bullet. Looks promising

Comment: GraphQL is definitely an amazing technology to be able to glue together the relationships between your data regardless of DB tech. Been playing around with it quite a bit in my free time as well

Comment: And Prisma is kind of what I was going to implement myself. Like having an arbitrary DB provider and "generating" a GraphQL endpoint from the database schema. That's one reason why I wanted to separate the relationships from the pure data.
But I could have never done it on the level it's done in Prisma. And even [Cosmos DB is in the making](https://github.com/graphcool/prisma/issues/1663) - exciting stuff! :D Can't wait - unfortunately there's no timeline yet.